# how to list joins in a SQL View

Tags: sql-server, join, view

I want to get a list of all joins in all views in a SQL Server database.

I realise that I can get the view definition which will include the source for the join statement. But I want it expressed in a list form - something like:
schema, view, join_sequence, column_sequence, table1_name, table1_col_name, table2_name, table2_col_name.

Anyone able to help?

I tried searching with Google to no avail.

Comment: There's no such thing easily available. Closest is to check dependencies perhaps. My google search turned up this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16 combined with sys.objects and sys.columns

Comment: [Answer to  similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75957293/option-in-scriptdom-to-retrieve-table-names-with-join-column-names/75959069#75959069).

Answer (score 0):

This query will show you every tables and views that are used in all of your views.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
```

This doc may help you : [Find SQL Server Views Where Table is used and List Tables in a View](https://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/find-sql-server-views-a-table-is-used-list-tables-in-a-database-view.aspx)